# How much does the Luke's Landspeeder (8092) weigh?

Tags: sets, star-wars, weight

I am considering buying [Luke's Landspeeder (8092)](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Luke-s-Landspeeder-8092).

[image]

However, because I will be traveling soon, I would like to know the set's weight first. LEGO.com doesn't list the weight, only the piece count and size, neither of which are too important to me.

So, including the minifigures if possible, what is the weight of the Luke's Landspeeder set?

Comment: I have created the tag [set-information] as it seemed the best for the job. If anyone finds a better tag, feel free to remove mine and add the other!

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for all your help! I will be buying the set shortly! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Bricklink's](http://www.bricklink.com/index.asp) set database keeps track of weight and dimensions. The weight listed includes packaging.

[Luke's Landspeeder](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=8092-1) weighs 272 grams.

Comment: Quick unit conversion with Google: 272 grams = 9.59451765 ounces.

Comment: Accepted this answer, as it is the clearest (and most upvoted).

Answer (score 14):

I just put the box on my balance, and the weight is 275.26 gr.
Yes, I have this in my shop.

Comment: Cheers for that Eric :)